Override navigate transition in compose navigation
I have an Android app that uses Compose navigation and nested navigation with several different modules. In XML-based navigation it was simple to add specific transitions to a given navigate action, but in compose I only seem to be able to set in on the composable/navigation level.
I have an outer navhost with it's own set of transitions:
 NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = ...,
        route = ...,
        enterTransition = ...,
        exitTransition = ...,
        popEnterTransition = ...,
        popExitTransition = ..,
    ) {

        composable(MainRoutes.Onboarding.route) {
            OnboardingScreen()
        }
        addItemNavigation(
            navController,
            onItemAdded = { 
                // I want to override the exit transition of this navigate action
                navController.navigate(
                   OnboardingRoutes.Onboarding.route)
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

The nested navigation has a different set of transitions:
fun NavGraphBuilder.addItemNavigation(
    navController: NavController,
    onItemAdded: () -> Unit
) {
    navigation(
        route = ...
        startDestination = ...
    ) {
        composable(
            route = ...,
            enterTransition = ...// Other transition than used by Main
            exitTransition = ... // Other transition than used by Main
            popEnterTransition = ...// Other transition than used by Main
            popExitTransition = ...// Other transition than used by Main
        ) {

The problem is that I want the exit transition to be different for the navigation triggered by the onItemAdded callback. Is it possible to override somehow? The addItemNavigation doesn't know about the outer navigation so I can't filter the composable level transitions without hard coding the string route.
